# Filter ModelAdmin by many_many relation

Tags: silverstripe

I'm managing the DataObject class 'trainer' with ModelAdmin. A trainer has a many_many relation to my other class 'language'.

On my 'trainer' class I'm manipulating the 'searchableFields' function to display a ListboxField in the filters area.

```
public function searchableFields() {
  $languagesField = ListboxField::create(
    'Languages',
    'Sprachen',
    Language::get()->map()->toArray()
  )->setMultiple(true);

  return array (
    'Languages' => array (
      'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
      'title' => 'Sprachen',
      'field' => $languagesField               
    )
  );
}
```

That works like expected and shows me the wanted ListboxField. The Problem is, after selecting 1 or 2 or whatever languages and submitting the form, I'm receiving

> [Warning] trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Is it possible here to filter with an many_many relation? And if so, how? Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

**Update:**

Full Error Message: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/56589337eea35

Trainer Class: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/56589441428d0

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that logic within a $searchable_fields parameter instead of the searchableFields() which actually constructs the searchable fields and logic.

PHP would be likely to throw an error if you go doing fancy form stuff within the array itself, so farm that form field off to a separate method in the same DataObject and simply call upon it.

See my example, I hope it helps.

```
/* Define this DataObjects searchable Fields */
private static $searchable_fields = array(
    'Languages' => array (
      'filter' => 'ExactMatchFilter',
      'title' => 'Sprachen',
      'field' => self::languagesField()               
    )
);

/* Return the searchable field for Languages */
public function languagesField() {
  return ListboxField::create(
    'Languages',
    'Sprachen',
    Language::get()->map()->toArray()
  )->setMultiple(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, did you ever use it like that? unfortunately it throws me an syntax error on  `'field' => self::languagesField()`. I think you aren't allowed to call a function here?

Comment: Can you copy in the error message itself. I have done it in a similar way before yes. SilverStripe is a difficult one to debug without seeing all the code sometimes.

Comment: Failing that, ignore the languagesField() method altogether and simply put your field declaration straight on to the 'field' key of the array. Typically, however, SilverStripe wants just the Class name for the field in question. So, try it with just ListboxField or Dropdown field as i'm not sure it's clever enough to accept multiple values from a Listbox just yet.

Comment: Also, perhaps use a dot notation on the field title.. So instead of Languages, use Languages.Title where Languages is the Class referred to in many_many and Title is the database column.

Comment: I've updated my question with the full error message and the Trainer Class.Also I think it's not possible to insert something else than an array or string in the $searchable_fields. Everytime I'll try it I'm receiving  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/domainstdb.dev.domain/mysite/code/DataObjects/Trainer.php on line 47` Line 47 would be the line with the 'field' key. It's necessary for me to filter this list by multiple values.

Comment: Thanks. Can you link me to the an sspaste of Language too. I'll test it all and mess around to try to find a solution for you.

Comment: that's great, thank you very much. Language just has a Title Field and the relation http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/56599b35a4131

Comment: Okay, it appears the ModelAdmin is expecting you to only pass in a string to select a single value. Do you receive the error message even when you select only one option? (Apologies, away from the PC so can't check for you at the moment). We may need to modify the search function on this ModelAdmin altogether.

Comment: Also, in-line with the documentation remove your searchableFields method and simply put this at the top of your code after the database fields.

'private static $searchable_fields = array(
      'Languages.Title',
);'

I would really like to hope that his works and confirms my theory that it only accepts one value by default.

Comment: yes, the error message also appears if you only select one item out of the listbox. If I'm just using the $searchable_fields like you mentioned in your comments, than yes, you get a text field that filters after one language with one value. does this help?

Comment: Okay, so whilst not a fix, I have just checked on the SilverStripe IRC chat history for this topic and another developer has brought it up recently. It would appear that the core of SilverStripe currently isn't able to do what you're asking within ModelAdmin's $searchable_fields functionality without making modifications to the core itself. You should be able to achieve this by building a custom extension of LeftAndMain with a form, which on submission, alters the view of the GridField, or alternatively, using a custom GridField extension. Refer to SilverStripe's documentation.

Comment: thank you for your research, could you post a link to the irc conversation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to override two methods - one in Trainer data object and one in TrainerModelAdmin. First one will make a field, second one will do filtering.

**Trainer Data Object:**

```
public function scaffoldSearchFields($_params = null)
{
    $fields = parent::scaffoldSearchFields($_params);

    // get values from query, if set
    $query = Controller::curr()->request->getVar('q');
    $value = !empty($query['Languages']) && !empty($query['Languages']) ? $query['Languages'] : array();

    // create a field with options and values
    $lang = ListboxField::create("Languages", "Sprachen", Language::get()->map()->toArray(), $value, null, true);

    // push it to field list
    $fields->push($lang);

    return $fields;
}
```

**Trainer Model Admin**

```
public function getList()
{
    $list = parent::getList();

    // check if managed model is right and is query set
    $query = $this->request->getVar('q');
    if ($this->modelClass === "Trainer" && !empty($query['Languages']) && !empty($query['Languages']))
    {

        // cast all values to integer, just to be sure
        $ids = array();
        foreach ($query['Languages'] as $lang)
        {
            $ids[] = (int)$lang;
        }

        // make a condition for query
        $langs = join(",", $ids);

        // run the query and take only trainer IDs
        $trainers = DB::query("SELECT * FROM Trainer_Languages WHERE LanguageID IN ({$langs})")->column("TrainerID");

        // filter query on those IDs and return it
        return $list->filter("ID", $trainers);
    }
    return $list;
}
```